# django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: data type character varying has no default operator class for access method "gin"

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-rest-framework

I am working on a django project, where I want to create gin indexing on my model's attribute.
I want to create gin indexing on

```
 SchoolName = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, null=False)
```

But, I am getting this error

```
 django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: data type character varying has no default operator class for access method "gin"
```

Help me to figure out this error

Comment: Can you put the traceback also the code where you use "gin" method?

Comment: i can not share the codes. But i can give you details. Actually i want to create indexing on charfield of my school model in djnago so that i can perform trigram search on the schoolname.

Comment: class Meta:
        indexes = [GinIndex(fields=['Field_Name'])]                                                                        
this is how i am creating gin index on schoolname attribute of school model.

Comment: @Sweta Looks like the SchoolName field does not have a built-in operator class in Postgres
See built-in operator classes here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/gin-builtin-opclasses.html
Also see Django documentation on how to handle this by installing a `btree_gin_extension` here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/postgres/indexes/#ginindex
This will allow support for `char`, `varchar` e.t.c

Comment: how to install BtreeGinExtension in ubuntu16.09

Comment: @Sweta Check my response below

Answer (score 8):

Create a migrations file to install the `BtreeGinExtension` to enable GIN Indexes to be built on `varchar` data types.

```
from django.contrib.postgres.operations import BtreeGinExtension

class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    ...

    operations = [
        BtreeGinExtension(),
        ...
    ]
```

References:

- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/gin-builtin-opclasses.html
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/postgres/indexes/#ginindex
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/postgres/operations/

Comment: Hi, which migrations file should I add this too if I already have data and an existing schema?

Comment: where does the migrations file go? what is the rest of the code?

Comment: This need to be added in the migrations files that gets generated after `./manage.py makemigrations` command